# How to compile project c++ with opencv on g++ ?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I'm used `ubuntu 14.04` and `opencv`  for `C++`
I want to run this project : `https://github.com/sharpe-developer/Realtime-Digit-Classifier` if i do :

```
 g++  -o l RealtimeDigitClassifier.cpp    `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

i get :

```
In file included from HogSvm.h:19:0,
                 from RealtimeDigitClassifier.cpp:16:
Svm.h:44:23: error: ‘cv::ml’ has not been declared
     void  SetType(cv::ml::SVM::Types type) const;
                       ^
Svm.h:44:38: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘type’
     void  SetType(cv::ml::SVM::Types type) const;
                                      ^
Svm.h:45:25: error: ‘cv::ml’ has not been declared
     void  SetKernel(cv::ml::SVM::KernelTypes kernel) const;
                         ^
Svm.h:45:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘kernel’
     void  SetKernel(cv::ml::SVM::KernelTypes kernel) const;
                                              ^
Svm.h:63:13: error: ‘ml’ is not a member of ‘cv’
     cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> m_svm;
             ^
Svm.h:63:13: error: ‘ml’ is not a member of ‘cv’
Svm.h:63:24: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> m_svm;
                        ^
RealtimeDigitClassifier.cpp: In function ‘void ProcessFrame(const HogSvm&, const HogSvm&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)’:
RealtimeDigitClassifier.cpp:60:34: error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list
     std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours;
                                  ^
RealtimeDigitClassifier.cpp:99:35: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
             putText(displayFrame, std::to_string(prediction), boundRect.tl() - Point(0, 5), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.4, Scalar(0, 0, 0));                
                                   ^
RealtimeDigitClassifier.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
RealtimeDigitClassifier.cpp:141:57: error: ‘CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH’ was not declared in this scope
     Size vidSize = Size(static_cast<int>(vidCapture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
                                                         ^
RealtimeDigitClassifier.cpp:142:57: error: ‘CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT’ was not declared in this scope
                         static_cast<int>(vidCapture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));
                                                         ^
```

what is the problem and how compile this projet ?

Comment: Did you build the OpenCV library yourself, or did you just download a precompiled one? In latter case, the _ml_ module may not have been included in your library. If that is the case, you need to build your OpenCV library by yourself.

Comment: exactly what should I do ? ? how i do this ?

Comment: Before you proceed, first check if the ml module really is not included in your OpenCV, because building OpenCV yourself may be a time consuming job. Try `#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>` and if the header is not found, then you should try building your OpenCV by following [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) guide.

Comment: 'c.cpp:1:26: fatal error: opencv2/ml.hpp: No such file or directory'

Comment: @devnglee thnx for this link : http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html but i have Ubuntu

Comment: Ah.. sorry for that. [This](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) is link to Linux installation guide.

Comment: @devnglee build == add a file for example ? or install all opencv ? for zero ?

Answer (score 0):

cv::ml has not been declared can suggest that you don't have openCV configured properly, error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’ can be caused by outdated libstdc++, try compiling with -std=c++11 flag

Comment: so what should I do ?

Comment: try compiling with -std=c++11 flag - this is for to_string() error, for opencv errors check your includes, because compiler is not able to find definitions of cv::ml(you can try adding -I flag with path to opencv includes to g++ compiling options)

Comment: please give me the command  , exactly  what should I do ? give me an example

Comment: g++ -std=c+11 -I/path_to_opencv/include -o l RealtimeDigitClassifier.cpp    `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

Comment: the same problem !

Comment: help me please !